# Regex to match multiple one and two digit numbers

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to match numbers that are either 1 or 2 digit (but not more) long so I can add leading zeroes. My input strings look like these:

```
LL.1 ETX 189 
1.20.3.4[8]
1.30.4[17]
229.c.85.8[4]
62.c.80.11
RR 60 H 2
R.60 H 2
Y.11.25[28]
Abc T.14.55
LL 108 ETX 189
Content 1364
```

With the application of the regex I would hope to identify the following:

```
LL.1 ETX 189    =>  match: 1
1.20.300.4[8]   =>  match: 1, 20, 4, 8
1.30.4[17]      =>  match: 1, 30, 4, 17
229.c.85.8[4]   =>  match: 85,8,4
62.c.80.11      =>  match: 62, 80, 11
RR 60 H 2       =>  match: 60, 2
R.60 H 2        =>  match: 60, 2
Y.11.25[28]     =>  match: 11, 25, 28
Abc T.14.55     =>  match: 14, 55
```

Whilst ignoring:

```
LL 108 ETX 189
Content 1364
```

I thought doing something as simple as: `([1-90-9]{1,2})` would work but this returns the following:

```
LL.1 ETX 189    =>  match: 1, 18, 9
1.20.300.4[8]   =>  match: 1, 20, 30, 0, 4, 8
1.30.4[17]      =>  match: 1, 30, 4, 17
229.c.85.8[4]   =>  match: 22, 9, 85,8,4
62.c.80.11      =>  match: 62, 80, 11
RR 60 H 2       =>  match: 60, 2
R.60 H 2        =>  match: 60, 2
Y.11.25[28]     =>  match: 11, 25, 28
Abc T.14.55     =>  match: 14, 55
LL 108 ETX 189  =>  match: 10, 8, 18, 9
Content 1364    =>  match: 13, 64
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

I've had a look at [this question: 'RegEx Expression /w limited length and chars'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40286910/regex-expression-w-limited-length-and-chars) and [this one: Regex match one digit or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548679/regex-match-one-digit-or-two)..

Comment: `[1-90-9]` is equivalent to `[0-9]`

Comment: `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}(?!\d)`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4lDVwn/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't `\d` include more characters than `[0-9]`?

Comment: No, unless you add the `/u` flag.

Comment: @Cid - :-) showing my ignorance when it comes to regex